# Can someone tell me why my code is running .Even i had commented my variables username , email ,password ,password2

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

```
//let username = document.getElementById('username');
//let email = document.getElementById('email');
//let password = document.getElementById('password');
//let password2 = document.getElementById('password2');


function check(arr) {
    arr.forEach((input) => {
        console.log(input);
    })
}
// Addeventlisteners
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    check([username, email, password, password2]);


})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Form Validation</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Register with us</h1>
        <form action="">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="">Username</label>
                <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter username">
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="">Email</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter email">
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="">Password</label>
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter password">
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password2" placeholder="Enter password again">
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>


    <script src="app.js">
    </script>
</body></html>
```

[output when i clicked the submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jsUz.png)

**I even cleared my cache but then it is showing the input tags. Can anybody help me i am not able to find the solution.This is my first time asking question here so i really don't know how to post question **

Comment: You're getting the elements by the id of the element: <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter username"> 
And you're specifying what elements you want to get here: check([username, email, password, password2]);

Comment: Any element with an ID will be added as a property to the `window` object, so `<input id="username"` exists as `window.username` which is then implicitly called as `username`.

Comment: @VLAZ  thanks this link solved my question. I changed my id ="username" to id="usernameop" it worked again even i did not write anything in my JS file thanks man.

Comment: @VictorÖhrström thanks  bro